# How to use the break between lines in a txt file to start a new list in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a txt file that is in this format:

```
1   Comparison  O
2   with    O
3   alkaline    B
4   phosphatases    I
5   and O
6   5   B
7   -   I
8   nucleotidase    I
9   .   O

1   Pharmacologic   O
2   aspects O
3   of  O
4   neonatal    O
5   hyperbilirubinemia  O
6   .   O

1   When    O
```

With tab separated columns of (sentence index, word, gene tag). There is a blank line between each sentence. I want to use this blank line as my delimiter to start a new sentence in my list. so for each sentence in my list of sentences, i want `['<s>', ...the sentence..., '</s>']` this is my current code:

```
sents=[]
testlines=[]

testfile=open("/Users/Desktop/Test.txt").read().split('\n')

for line in testfile:
    if not len(line.strip())==0:
        index,word,tag= line.split()
        if index == "1":
            sents=['<s>', word]
            testlines.append(sent)
    else:
        sents.append('</s>')
```

however, the only thing that shows up in my testlines when i print is a repeat of the last sentence in the txt file 100 times. like so:

```
[['<s>', 'To', 'understand', 'the', 'molecular', 'regulation', 'of', 'these', 'genes', 'in', 'thyroid', 'cells', ',', 'the', 'effect', 'of', 'thyroid', 'transcription', 'factor', '1', '(', 'TTF', '-', '1', ')', 'and', 'the', 'paired', 'domain', '-', 'containing', 'protein', '8', '(', 'Pax', '-', '8', ')', 'on', 'the', 'transcriptional', 'activity', 'of', 'the', 'deiodinase', 'promoters', 'were', 'studied', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'To', 'understand', 'the', 'molecular', 'regulation', 'of', 'these', 'genes', 'in', 'thyroid', 'cells', ',', 'the', 'effect', 'of', 'thyroid', 'transcription', 'factor', '1', '(', 'TTF', '-', '1', ')', 'and', 'the', 'paired', 'domain', '-', 'containing', 'protein', '8', '(', 'Pax', '-', '8', ')', 'on', 'the', 'transcriptional', 'activity', 'of', 'the', 'deiodinase', 'promoters', 'were', 'studied', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'To', 'understand', 'the', 'molecular', 'regulation', 'of', 'these', 'genes', 'in', 'thyroid', 'cells', ',', 'the', 'effect', 'of', 'thyroid', 'transcription', 'factor', '1', '(', 'TTF', '-', '1', ')', 'and', 'the', 'paired', 'domain', '-', 'containing', 'protein', '8', '(', 'Pax', '-', '8', ')', 'on', 'the', 'transcriptional', 'activity', 'of', 'the', 'deiodinase', 'promoters', 'were', 'studied', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'To', 'understand', 'the', 'molecular',
```

is there a reason it is only repeating the last line? also, i don't need any of the tags for now i just want the sentences. anything will help, thanks so much!

Comment: Will your file ever start with a blank line? 

There's a problem with how you open the file. 'testfile=open("/Users/Desktop/Test.txt").read().split('\n')'

Try using // with open("/Users/Desktop/Test.txt",'r') as f: //
and then iterate over each line with // for line in f: //

Comment: that worked! thanks!

Comment: Cool. I've added a more concise code in the answer. don't forget to upvote / accept if you like :)

Comment: awesome, really appreciate the help!!

Comment: you're welcome! :) 

A few upvotes would help too :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your text file never starts with a blank line, below code would work.

Use of testlines can be avoided. Just start with "`<s>`" and append the word for each line followed by a "`</s><s>`" for every blank line.

```
sents=['<s>']

with open("/Users/Desktop/Test.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line.strip()) > 0:
            sents.append(line.strip()[1])
        else:
            sents.append('</s>')
            sents.append('<s>')
```

That should do it in fewer lines.